# Swift - How can I resume URLRequest after app shut down and reopened

Tags: ios, swift, networking

#### Question

If the app crashes for some reason while sending a lot of requests, how can I resume it?

**Let's assume the following situation:**

```
for i in 0..<50 {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: postMessage) { data, response, error in
        ...
    }
    
    if i == 25 {
        // App shut down
        exit(0)
    }
}


// App reopened
for i in 25..<50 {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: postMessage) { data, response, error in
        ...
    }
}
```

As an example, if you send multiple messages in an app and failed, it starts sending messages again from where it failed.

How can I implement this? I tried using `FileManager` to cache each requests in local disk but it seems giving too many overheads to device.

Are there any effective methods I can use? I will be really appreciated if you give me some ideas.

Comment: Since these are `dataTasks`, I don't think you can resume them per se unlike a download task. So in your example, you want to restart the requests 25 - 50, is this what you want ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank Yes, that's what I meant. 0-24 before shut down,  25-50 after reopened.

Comment: The simplest approach would be to queue your requests in `UserDefaults` and dequeue them once they have been completed. So when your app restarts, you check what requests are still in your queue and relaunch them. A more sophisticated approach would be to use `CoreData` replace `UserDefaults` as your persistent store.

Comment: @ShawnFrank Thanks for your opinion. I think`UserDefault` is good solution. But does `UserDefault` have any advantages over `FileManager` except for convenience?

Comment: I think you might have to do some tests. I believe `UserDefaults` has a limited storage capacity unlike `FileManager` and it is best practice to store things like user preferences and similar lightweight settings. Because of this, I tend to think it might be optimized and faster than `FileManager` which is for sure reading and writing to disk - but this is just my theory. I think you will find a better way to make your decision by reading: https://www.donnywals.com/deciding-where-to-store-data/

Comment: @ShawnFrank I see.. It really helped a lot. Thank you again!